# How to find this limit correctly?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How to find the limit

```
Limit[n*Sin[2*Pi*Exp[1]*n!], n -> Infinity]    ?
```

Mathematica 10 outputs

```
 Interval[{-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

which is not correct since the one equals $2\pi$, being a known limit.

Comment: Hm.. The output makes sense to me. At least it wouldn't make sense that the limit was `2 Pi`.

Comment: Hm.. well, I suppose you may be right, in which case that is a pretty awesome limit :). Maybe you can provide some reference?

Comment: @MarkMcClure `ListLinePlot@
 Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000}, 
  Table[N[n*Sin[2*Pi*E*n!], 100], {n, 0, 400}]]`

Comment: @belisarius Well, yeah, but that's a discrete plot indicating the limit is $2\pi$ ( I assume, I'm on my iPhone).

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yes, you may assume you're on your iPhone :)

Comment: Colleagues, I don't think Plot[n*Sin[2*Pi*Exp[1]*n!], {n, 1, 20}] is correct.

Comment: The domain of n must be given, otherwiese the Problem is not well defined. Simply consider Limit[Sin[2 pi n],n->oo].

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze : That's another cup of tea. You introduce into consideration a different function than the one in my question.

Comment: @ user64494: it's just a simplified example showing the importance of the Domain in which die Limit is to be considered.

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze : What is a non-simplified example?

Comment: Re: Plot, might do better with `ListPlot[N[Table[n*Sin[2*Pi*Exp[1]*n!], {n, 1, 20}], 100]]` (would be nice if `ListPlot` took a `WorkingPrecision` option, like `Plot` does).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The limit is definitely computed correctly.  Keep in mind that `Limit` *assumes* the variable (`n`, in this case) is continuous. Thus, this is a specific example of the general fact that $f(x)\sin(g(x))$ oscillates back and forth over the whole real line, whenever $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both increase to $\infty$ with $x$.  A plot verifies this is correct.

```
Plot[n*Sin[2*Pi*Exp[1]*n!], {n, 0, 10},
  PlotPoints -> 400]
```

[image]

Again, `n` represents a continuous variable (since that's how `Plot` works) and $n!$ is computed via the continuous analog of the factorial, namely using the Gamma function.

---

Now, the *discrete* limit

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }n \sin (2\pi  e n!)=2\pi$$

is a separate issue.  Proving this is a bit tricky but can be done as follows. First, it's a pretty basic fact of calculus that

$$\frac{\sin (a x)}{x}\to a$$

as $x\to 0$. It's not too much more work to show that

$$\frac{\sin \left(a x+O\left(x^2\right)\right)}{x}\to a,$$

where $O\left(x^2\right)$ represents an expression that is bounded 
by a constant times $x^2$. So, now, let's examine the argument 
$2\pi n! e$ of the sine in the original question. This all hinges on the standard expression of $e$ in terms of an infinite series:

$$
e = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}.
$$

Thus,

\begin{align}
2\pi  n!e &= 2\pi  n! \sum _ {k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k!}=2\pi \left(\sum _ {k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\sum _ {k=n+2}^{\infty } \frac{n!}{k!}\right) \\
 &= 2\pi\left(M+\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=\frac{2\pi }{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\mod 2\pi
\end{align}

Taking $x=1/n$, we get the desired result.

Of course, this can be tested numerically using beli's plot, though I'd prefer `ListPlot` to `ListLinePlot`, since this is truly a discrete phenomenon.

```
ListPlot[Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000}, 
  Table[N[n*Sin[2*Pi*E*n!], 100], {n, 0, 400}]],
  Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{0, 2 Pi}, {400, 2 Pi}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Limit` does not handle integer assumptions (as in discrete variables).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That is what I thought. But, then, how do I explain the fact that `Limit[n^2 Sin[2*n*Pi], n->Infinity, Assumptions->Element[n, Integers]]==0`?

Comment: I suppose that `Assumptions` in `Limit` might simply be applied to simplify the expression ahead of the computation. That would explain the difference in the results and be dismissed as designed. A genuine domain restriction would be more properly dealt with as a third argument.

Comment: Right on all counts. I should have stated that `Limit` does not do anything beyond what `Simplify` or `Refine`1 might do in terms of handling integrality assumptions.